# Отличия TASM и NASM

Tags: ассемблер, nasm, tasm

Есть ли какие-то кардинальные отличия в TASM по сравнению с NASM? И стоит ли вообще его начинать изучать, если нет опыта в программирование на ассемблере?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/326078/

Comment: Отличия есть, довольно кардинальные. В целом, "средний" исходник для TASM не скомпилируется с помощью NASM. Я бы не советовал использовать TASM вообще, т.к. он давно заброшен (лет 10 как минимум), но только проблема в том, что большинство примеров в интернете как раз в синтаксисе TASM или MASM (причем, для DOS, что как бы немного далеко от повседневной практики).

Comment: Из личного опыта - я начинал с TASM, но в итоге перешел на FASM, у него также немного другой синтаксис (все же ближе к NASM, чем к TASM), но пользоваться им удобнее (одноэтапная компиляция без отдельного этапа линковки, не нужно запоминать кучу ключей командной строки для компиляции - из одного и того же исходника всегда получится файл одного и того же вида - целевой формат задается в самом исходнике)

Answer (score 0):

TASM используется при работе в Dos. NASM в Linux. Команды ассемблера в принципе одинаковые, но структура исходников разная.

Comment: "TASM используется при работе в Dos. NASM в Linux." - не совсем верно. TASM32 вполне можно использовать для программирования для Windows, NASM можно использовать для Linux, Windows, DOS, *BSD, etc.